# How to find two types of files: executables and text files

Tags: command-line, find

I would like to find two types of files (executables and text files) and create soft links for them. My solution so far is:

```
find src -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -executable -exec ln -fs {} . \;; \
find src -name "*.txt" -exec ln -fs {} . \;
```

The directory structure is:

```
src
src/lapack
src/plasma
```

I would like to pick up the executables only from the `src` and the text files `*.txt` from the `lapack` and `plasma` subdirectories.

I would like find a more elegant solution that would combine two `find` calls into one. I have attempted to use the `-o` flag, but I encounter problems with the `-maxdepth` option.

**Update:**

The combined command I'm trying is:

```
find src -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -executable -o -path src -name "*.txt"
```

But it does not pick up the text files in the subdirectories. I believe this is due to the `-maxdepth 1` flag before the `-o`.

Comment: You can use `file` command and then do a `grep text` for text files and `grep ELF` for executable.

Comment: put the command line you've try with `-o`

Comment: `-maxdepth` is not a test, it is an option.  In a `find` expression, options evaluate to `true` and affect all tests, including those appearing earlier in the expression.

Comment: Have you considered just leaving it as two commands?  That's going to be a lot more readable (IMO) than any variation that does the whole job in a single `find` command, and that's a strong reason to prefer such an approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with GNU find or other find that supports `-path`, but I don't think it's more elegant.

```
find src \( -type f -executable ! -path 'src/*/*' -o -name '*.txt' \) \
     -exec ln -fs {} . +
```

You can use zsh instead. Its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) are more concise than find syntax.

```
ln -sf src/*/*(N*.) src/**/*.txt .
```